# Why can't I discard my own checkouts?

Tags: check-out

I am having a repeated problem where I check out a document, but am not able to discard my checkout subsequently. What could be the cause? Background: I am a user not an administrator; our SharePoint Foundation 2010 system was set up some time back and we no longer have SharePoint experts onsite, so I suspect things have gotten outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be because you have uploaded a document which has no checked in version, so Sharepoint cannot discard the check out as there would be no previous version.

Instead, try checking in the document - then checking it out again. After doing this, you might be able to use the Discard check out feature.

Comment: When I try to check it in, I get "This document was checked out to your local drafts folder but the local copy could not be found or is on a different computer. Upload the local changes or discard your checkout to continue editing." I've only used the same computer to handle this document. When I try to discard my checkout, the button is grayed out and if I click it anyway I get an empty error box with just an OK button. This behavior is not specific to this document - this happens all the time on other documents. Any ideas?

Comment: When I later downloaded a read only version then uploaded it again, the checkout disappeared and everything was OK. I just had to ignore the checkout (I had thought it would prevent me, but it didn't). This solution works.

Comment: If someone else is having this problem: these "ghost" checkouts seem to appear after SharePoint hangs, which is often because it is running really slowly.